# Embedded ConfigFile In Exe file

Tags: c#, app-config

I want to create application which is App.config file data like connectionString etc... to embedded in Exe file

when application release .exe file after create exe file and after delete app.config file
 how run application without app.config file

how to embedded app.config file in .exe file.

my config file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>       
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DataBaseEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.DataBase.csdl|res://*/Model.DataBase.ssdl|res://*/Model.DataBase.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=127.0.0.1;initial catalog=DataBase;persist security info=True;user id=abc;password=123;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

my Program :

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
        using (DataBaseEntities entities = new DataBaseEntities())
        {
            List<User> user= objEntities.UserTable.ToList();              
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

atfer Delete app.config file run application and retrive data as it is.

Comment: Sorry if I Get it wrong: you want to have the app.config to be edited after compilation. But as soon as you delete it, you would like to keep the last configs from the app.config?... You should think about the use case of a config. Otherwise i would save it as a static read-only property in the program.

Comment: If the content changes I guess the security checks for the exe will fail. But I may be wrong there. Can anybody comment on this??

Answer (score 5):

You have to set Build Action for app.config to "Embedded Resource" in the Property of the app.config. It will disappear as a file in the bin folder and will be included to *.exe file

Comment: It doesnt work. It doesn't disappear and if deleted, the app fails to start.

Answer (score -1):

App.config is config - it is intended to be configurable. If you don't want to use it, then hard code the values as constants (and/or have app settings with default values) and configure with code.

Comment: first time create app.config file after then delete app.config file then application run .